# Moving the Pagefile to a non-system drive fails in Windows 11, 22H2

Tags: pagefile, windows-11

I have Windows 11 Pro, 22H2(Build 22621.963), and I am running out of space on system drive, and I need to move the pagefile.sys to a non-system drive (other than C:)

I have tried relocating the pagefile.sys to a non-system drive, and it always fails (even after trying all the options to relocate the pagefile.sys, and restarting the system)

The steps I followed, as suggested by one MS Forum thread.

```
System Properties >> Advanced tab >> Change button under Virtual
memory.
    
    Uncheck the checkbox next to "Automatically manage paging file size for all drives"
    
    Click on the drive currently holding pagefile.sys (System drive C:)
    
    Click on No paging file/or/Change it to some Value higher than minimal required.
    
    Click Set
    
    Click on OK
    
    From the same location, select another drive that you want to move pagefile.sys to (D:\ )
    
    Click on System Managed Size
    
    Click Set
    
    perform a clean boot
    
    restart the computer
```

After trying these steps, the system still has pagefile on C:\ drive and no pagefile on the D:\ drive.

**Expected:** Pagefile.sys should move to D:\ drive, after the reboot.

**Actual:** Windows does not create or use any non-system drive Pagefile.

**My other investigation:** I have followed MS Forms for an answer and there are multiple hoola-hoops they want you to jump, and all fails.

MS Forum have an official ticket for this as well, un-answered I might add. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/cannot-relocate-pagefilesys-to-secondary-drive/7dfbed85-c295-470a-ae41-7d18995881e8

Last I checked the official stance on the issue is "If the problem is a major inconvenience, you can move back to Windows 10 while waiting until you respond to a feedback request." - Feb 28 2022.

It seems like either I am doing something fundamentally wrong or there is a outstanding defect with MS Windows 11.

Comment: Have you rebooted?

Comment: Pagefiles are best living on the system drive. Better to move something else instead.  Page files are usually fairly small if set to automatic.

Comment: @harrymc, as mentioned in the question itself I did reboot, multiplke times (everytime I tried to move the Pagefile)

Comment: @John I have a 64GB RAM PC, and heavy workload, with need for a pagefile of significant size for optimal windows performance, else it is taking few dedicated CPUs to keep swapping data in and out of the pagefile, hence bringing down system performance.

Comment: I do not quite understand. Moving a pagefile to a new drive will not improve performance. Replacing your main drive with a very fast, large,  NVMe SSD drive generally will improve performance.

Comment: Try : Boot in Safe mode, relocate pagefile, reboot in Safe mode, check if the setting has persisted, if it did then try a normal boot. Please report on what happened.

Comment: @John, The current drives are all NVMe drives. I cannot extend the c:\ drive, and the only other way is to use the windows supported feature of adding pagefiles on other drives
 - which also will be NVMe drives
 - Adding pagefiles on non-system drives used to work on this system as well until some latest update, which made it fail

Comment: You need to get a C: drive that is about 512GB to run Windows, all of Windows stuff, all of Your stuff and have space left over. Having drives to small to run Windows is (to me) a very short sited strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this applies to Windows 11 (or 10).  I do remember this does apply to Windows 7 and 8, so it might still be true.  I would test, but I am at work, so I cant.

Windows MUST have a page file on the system drive, even if its small.  I dont remember the exact size, but it has to be large enough to hold some data for a reason I cant remember off the top of my head.  You can then add *another* page file to other drives.

Try reducing it in half on your system drive and putting the other half on another drive.  If it works, you can play with the numbers to get it smaller.

Answer (score 0):

From experience, the page file on the system drive needs to be larger than physical memory - 1.5 times is what's recommended.  This is because a BSOD dumps memory (optionally) and it will only dump it on the system drive.  If there is not enough space allocated then your fault gets a fault and it becomes hard to determine what is going wrong.

The minimum size can be reduced if you alter crash dump settings

> **Support for system crash dumps**
> A system crash (also known as a "bug check" or a "Stop error") occurs when the system can't run correctly. The dump file that is produced from this event is called a system crash dump. A page file or dedicated dump file is used to write a crash dump file (Memory.dmp) to disk. Therefore, a page file or a dedicated dump file must be large enough to support the kind of crash dump selected. Otherwise, the system can't create the crash dump file.

> **Minimum page file size**
> Varies based on page file usage history, amount of RAM (RAM ÷ 8, max 32 GB), and crash dump settings.

From [learn.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/introduction-to-the-page-file)

> The optimal size for a pagefile is 1:1.5, ei: 4GB ram -> pagefile 6GB. However, if you let Windows handle it, if it needs the space, it can the requirements automatically.

From [MS Support Engineer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/optimal-page-file-size/3c68f053-1248-48c9-bd10-72874834d595)

The recommendation would be to

- Obtain a larger system drive.
- Or shift some programs away from the system drive by reinstalling them on other drives.
- As a last resort, you can recover some disk space on your system drive by using symbolic links.  For example, you could move the temp folder or downloads folder to another drive and put a symbolic link to them.  Once you have that working, you can try shifting other folders.  I realize that some users here are against these links.  But they are available for a reason and you can use them if stuck.  These are made using the command **mklink**.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, and the reason for my case is that Windows refuses to create pagefile on non-Bitlocked drives, if your system drive is encrypted.

I enabled Bitlocker on another non-system drive, and choose that drive for the pagefile while keeping the pagefile on C:/ minimal (I used a maximum of 1GB) in the same way as in the posted question. Now Windows seems to use the newly assigned drive for pagefile.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is not recommended,  The pagefile on the boot drive has to be larger than installed ram.  In case of error Windows dumps memory only to the boot drive.  See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem.

After doing the same steps double checkig everything, no matter how many times I rebooted or anything I still had pagefile on C:.

I booted in safe mode (msconfig, boot tab) the pagefile was gone. I didn't do anything else, but booting in network safe mode.
Know the space is free on my C:\ and I have a pagefile on D:.

I hope this works for you too.